# Accessing SQLite database from command line

Tags: android, sqlite, adb

I am trying to access SQLite database from command line for an android application I have developed. I type `adb shell`  to connect to the device and then `sqlite3` to connect to the database. `sqlite3` gives me the following an error:
 /system/bin/sh: sqlite3: not found

Comment: What did you get after entering adb shell?

Comment: Is it a device or an emulator?

Comment: "sqlite3: not found" <-- It means there is no sqlite3 binary in your PATH. Step #1 is to find it (or get it).

Comment: It's a device. Where to find it?

Answer (score 0):

Try typing "adb shell type sqlite3" to see whether sqlite3 is available in your device or not.

For my device, it's showing as follows

$ adb shell type sqlite3
   -->   sqlite3 is a tracked alias for /system/xbin/sqlite3

Answer (score -1):

```
 // Below code works on windows platform.. tried on windows 7 and windows 8 
 // This is vb script code.. save with .vb extention. 
 // any problems in saving.. please copy paste any vb file from ur system,take that second file ,open it with notepad and clear all contents, paste the below code as i did same.
 // double click to run file. output shown will ur all tables. and u can continue with      the own sql statements

 // note : works with only one emulator. many emulator are supported. 
 // please dont try this code with mobile, you wont be able to access mobile database

// start of script


Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 // set ur path to platform tools in ur sdk
strApp = "E:\Android\sdk\platform-tools"

arrPath = Split(strApp, "\")

 For i = 0 to Ubound(arrPath)
  strAppPath = strAppPath & arrPath(i) & "\"
Next 



WshShell.CurrentDirectory = strAppPath

WshShell.Run ("cmd.exe")
WScript.Sleep 50
WshShell.SendKeys "adb shell" 
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

// put ur package name and database name over here. please put ur db name with .db          extension



WshShell.SendKeys "sqlite3 /data/data/package_name/databases/database_name"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WshShell.SendKeys ".tables"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Set objShell = Nothing
// script ends
```

Comment: take out all comments before create a vb file

Comment: before downvoting did one tried running above vb script code ?